# How are TLS master secrets (for HTTPS) stored server-side?

Tags: ssl, https

I.e. are they stored in a database, on a disk? Or does it depend on the implementation used? Also how is each secret/key distinguished from the next, are they stored with session data of the relevant client?

Comment: It is stored with the TLS session data, but where depends entirely on the implementation. Apache HTTPD for example has a [session cache](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_ssl.html#sslsessioncache) which can be on disk. Off topic. Close-voters please note: this question is not unclear.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart I've been staring at your comment for 3 hours and I can't make head or tail of it. TLS *is* a protocol and it has its *own* sessions, which therefore have 'session data', which includes all the certificate and key material that were used to set up the session, and the current session key.